# Git Gui Unstaged Changes stuck on excel macro-associated temporary file

Tags: excel, git, git-gui

I am a solo developer tracking my project changes through Git Gui. Recently, in one of my projects, I incorporated an excel macro .xlsm file. This created a temporary file of the same name with `"~$"` prepended to it, which gets stuck in Unstaged Changes. I can continue my commits by staging necessary files one-at-a-time by hand, but this is slow and annoying. When I click on the `"~$..."` file I get a pop-up error saying `Error loading file: couldn't open 'path/~$filename.xlsm': permission denied`. I can't figure out how to get Git Gui to forget about this, or deal with it myself in some other way. Did some searching. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `.gitignore`. If `.gitignore` does not exist, create in the root directory of your project and add

```
~$filename.xlsm
```